# Changing a users roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have an asp where I have radio buttons to pick a role for a user.  In the aspx I want to change the role on the user removing old ones and adding the new one, simple enough.

The problem is that the ApplicationUserManager I get has all async methods. Async and asp pages do not get along very well giving the error:

An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

For my async attempt that gave this error I call an async Task.

```
    protected async void GrantPrivlege_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationUserManager manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        string groupId = AspHelper.StringGuid(Request.Url.Segments[3]);
        string userId = Request.Url.Segments[4];
        IList<string> roles = await  WaitGetRoles(userId);
        foreach (string roleStr in roles) {
            await WaitRemoveFromRole(userId, roleStr);
        }
        ApplicationUser.RoleEnum role = (ApplicationUser.RoleEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(ApplicationUser.RoleEnum), PrivilegeList.SelectedValue, true);
        await WaitAddToRole(userId, role.ToString());      
        Response.Redirect("/Admin/GroupAdmin/" + groupId);
    }

    protected async Task<IList<string>> WaitGetRoles(string userId)
    {
        ApplicationUserManager manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        IList<string> roles = await manager.GetRolesAsync(userId);
        return roles;
    }

    protected async Task<bool> WaitRemoveFromRole(string userId, string roleStr)
    {
        ApplicationUserManager manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        await manager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(userId, roleStr);
        return true;
    }

    protected async Task<bool> WaitAddToRole(string userId, string roleStr)
    {
        ApplicationUserManager manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        await manager.AddToRoleAsync(userId, roleStr); 
        return true;     
    }
```

The real puzzle form is that the Admin Register page that comes with the Visual Studio project has the AddRole method has no async calls.

Both the Register page and my page are an aspx with a aspx.cs that create the manage with

```
ApplicationUserManager manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

and both do it in a onclick method.  I really wish I got the Register ApplicationUserManager using UserManagerExtensions that has AddToRoles instead of the manage with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity with all async.  The difference is probably being logged in while the Register asp is not, logging in after.

Would someone please tell me how to get a  UserManagerExtensions version of ApplicationUserManager or if that is not possible how to get async working in a aspx reliably.

I am blocked as this point, I will keep Googling for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that posting this question gave me some new Google terms to try and I found http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx which shows how to do an asynchronous aspx in ASP.Net.

Putting async is true the page tag was cool because then Visual Studio added an async tag to all my calls and magically my await async calls work fine.

```html
// I added Async="true" to my aspx page
<%@ Page Async="true"  Title="Async" Language="C#" CodeBehind="Async.aspx.cs" Inherits="Whatever"  %>

// and then in my aspx.cs file await GetRolesAsync() works now
    public async Task LoadPage()
    {
        string userId = Request.Url.Segments[4];
        ApplicationUserManager manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        IList<string> roles = await manager.GetRolesAsync(userId);
        if (roles.Count > 0) {
            PrivilegeList.SelectedValue = roles[0];
        }                   
    }
```

Running the page with the forced async calls from ApplicationUserManager works fine now.